Vlookup inconsistence or confusion(?) using true range lookup
I want to make a commission that is within a certain percentage range. However, the results given are not matched, instead the grade is. Does it have anything to do with the percent value?

The commission
=VLOOKUP(C6;A$1:B$3;1;TRUE)
The grade
=VLOOKUP(C6;B$1:C$3;2;TRUE)

Please post your data as text, not image.

Certainly, you are not using the VLOOKUP() function in the way it has to be used as it works from Left to Right. This is because the LOOKUP() value is Sales Amount whereas in the Table Array the Lookup_Value is in second column. Try using the following formula:


• Formula used in cell E6
=VLOOKUP($C6,IF({1,0},B$1:B$3,A$1:A$3),2,1)


• Formula used in cell F6
=VLOOKUP($C6,IF({1,0},B$1:B$3,C$1:C$3),2,1)


Alternatively, can use XLOOKUP()
• For Commission
=XLOOKUP(C6:C10,B1:B3,A1:A3,,-1)


• For Grade
=XLOOKUP(C6:C10,B1:B3,C1:C3,,-1)


Or Use LOOKUP() function for Commission:
=LOOKUP(C6:C10,B1:B3,A1:A3)


Or Use LOOKUP() function for Grade:
=LOOKUP(C6:C10,B1:B3,C1:C3)


Similarly can use INDEX()+MATCH()` combination:
=INDEX(A1:A3,MATCH(C6:C10,B1:B3,1))


=INDEX(C1:C3,MATCH(C6:C10,B1:B3,1))


Or Using VLOOKUP() with one single formula to spill:
=VLOOKUP(C6,CHOOSE({1,2,3},B$1:B$3,A$1:A$3,C$1:C$3),{2,3},1)


Likewise above with XLOOKUP()
=XLOOKUP(C6,B$1:B$3,HSTACK(A$1:A$3,C$1:C$3),,-1)



The index / match methods here need some absolute references ($) to make them usable if copied down to other rows

@AdamV Sir, those don't require because it will spill for the whole array! Hence doesn't require to copied down.
